# Prevent bash completion from printing the reply twice

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I am having difficulties making my bash completion script behave as expected.

Below is the most simplified version of what I am trying to do, and a screencast of the problem.

Everything works great, with the exception of one case:

When there is one match only in the completion, when I press Tab twice, it will print the same command twice, which is not the intended effect.

In my completion case, I am only interested in completing the first argument (i.e. the "subcommand"). I thought that the `if [ "$#" -gt "2" ]` line below should have prevented this case, but it does not - since `COMP_LINE` is still not updated after the first tab.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

send_completions() {
  if [[ -z "$COMP_LINE" ]]; then
    return
  fi

  set $COMP_LINE

  if [ "$#" -gt "2" ]; then
    return
  fi

  compgen -W "one two test" "$2"
}

send_completions
```

Enable the completion by running:

```
$ complete -C './complete.sh' asd
```

then type `asd o<tab><tab>` to see the problem.

[image: screencast]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use a script for the completion or would a function be ok?

Comment: I need to use a script in this case. But, I also tried an implementation with a function (`complete -F ...`) and the issue was present there as well

Comment: Its not the problem here as far as I could test. This variable holds the correct argument count. Notice the `set $COMP_LINE` line - which splits the `$COMP_LINE` variable into the `$1, $2, $3, ...` variables.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of `COMP_LINE` at this very moment:

```
$ asd one <TAB>
```

You will notice that the value is:

```
declare -x COMP_LINE="asd one "
```

Which will result in two positional parameters after you issue `set` and your condition will not get triggered. Try typing an additional character: `$ asd one o<TAB>` and you will see that your condition will get triggered correctly and nothing will be completed.

---

Most completions I have seen were done using a function. In fact, checking all completions defined on my system now (most of them default), **none** of them are done using a script.

Using a function has some benefits, for example the `COMP_WORDS` array that **respects** quotes. Your script could be rewritten roughly like this:

```
_asd_comp() {
    (( COMP_CWORD > 1 )) && return
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} IFS=$' \t\n'
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "one two three" -- "$cur") )    
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _asd_comp asd
```

I added the `-o` options so that default completions are performed after the first argument. You can read more about that in [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins).

---

The only thing that comes to mind as to how to change your script, I guess you could add rather unclean condition, such as:

```
(( $# > 1 )) && [[ ${COMP_LINE: -1} = " " ]] && return
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helps. But after trying to change my code to use a function instead, I realized I really prefer using the script version, one of the reasons being the desire to stay with one script (that needs to be executed). If I go with the function route, I have to provide a second script to the users, so they can source it rather than execute it. This is my understanding at least. (and the last part of the answer does not work).

Comment: @DannyB What version of `bash` are you running? Older versions of `bash` had problems with the `-1`. You can try `${COMP_LINE:${#COMP_LINE}-1}` instead. Well, function/script is up to you to decide. Some global completion script that would be getting sourced sounds good considering the benefits.